# How do I make a comment within SQLDF code?

Tags: r, sqldf

I am working through someone's extensive SQLDF code, and want to place comments to help me understand it. I know how to comment in R (outside of the SQLDF statement), but how would I make a comment within the code?

Something like this:

```
a <- 1:5
b <- c("a","b","c","d","e")

df <- data.frame(a,b)

sqldf('select 
          b,
          count(a) # add a comment here
      from df 
      group by 1')
```

Comment: Thanks for finding this for me. I didn't find it earlier because the question name is unclear, but the solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL comment character is '--' (at least in MSSQL, the one I know) and it seems to work here too:

```
sqldf('select 
          b,
          count(a) -- add a comment here
      from df 
      group by 1')
```

Comment: Thanks G Gamba - that is perfect. I found another solution (below), but like yours better.


sqldf('select 
          b,
          count(a) /* add a comment here  */
      from df 
      group by 1')